How come IPv6 works with UFW default deny outgoing?
So I have 2 questions.
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 VM with netplan configured in the following way:
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
      - 10.100.100.100/24
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      accept-ra: true
      ipv6-privacy: true
      ...

The ufw on this VM is enabled and configured with ufw default deny outgoing. I have several rules configured for specific ingoing and outgoing traffic, so everything works as expected. However:

In kernel logs, I see the following message repeated every 2 minutes:
[UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:0215:beef:abcd:bd1f DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001:0002 LEN=90 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=843478 PROTO=UDP SPT=546 DPT=547 LEN=50

My netplan is configured with dhcp6: false. Why is this VM attempting to communicate with a DHCP6 server on ff02::1:2 despite of that?

With ufw blocking all outgoing traffic, how come accept-ra: true works? I do get my IPv6 address through SLAAC, which indicates that the VM is successfully sending RS messages to ff02::2 and it's not getting blocked like ff02::1:2 does.


UFW has a set of built-in rules that are applied before user configured policies: https://git.launchpad.net/ufw/plain/conf/before6.rules
These are to make sure that users don’t have to worry about breaking their own system. One of the rules is:
-A ufw6-before-output -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type router-solicitation -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT

Explicitly allowing outbound router solicitations.

Ok, thanks. This answers question 2. What about question 1, why despite dhcp6 set to false in netplan it still tries to communicate on ff02::1:2 ?
